# How to remove image tile layer from google map javascript api?

Tags: javascript, image, api, dictionary

I tried to show image tiles on google map after initializing google map javascript API. 
That worked OK!
But I want to show original google map again that was hidden by image tiles. 
Is there any solution? Below are my codes.

```js
// my codes

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*******&callback=initMap">
</script> 

...

function initMap() {

            var center = {lat: -34.980035, lng: 127.426107};

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
                {
                zoom : 11,
                center : center
            });

...

            layer = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
                name : layerID,
                getTileUrl : function(coord, zoom) {
                    var url = TILE_URL.replace('{x}', coord.x).replace('{y}',
                            coord.y).replace('{z}', zoom);
                    return url;
                },
                tileSize : new google.maps.Size(800,800),
                minZoom : 9,
                maxZoom : 20
            });

            map.mapTypes.set(layerID, layer);
            map.setMapTypeId(layerID);  

//  here some code for recovering original map....  ?
```

Thanks for reading my text !